# prefixing url_for() behind reverse proxy

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Scenario: 
Flask + flask-login behind an HTTP reverse proxy

Flask app at http://localhost:5000/
Public app at http://example.com/my_fancy_app/

The reverse proxy sends requests to http://example.com/my_fancy_app/[stuff] to http://localhost:/5000/[stuff]

Using the login_required wrapper:

```
login_required uses url_for() which redirects back out to http://example.com/[stuff]
```

I need it to redirect to http://example.com/my_fancy_app/[stuff]

Before I fork login_required and add `_external=True` or support for FlaskView to `url_for()` calls, is there a good way to set a prefix for all generated URLs in my app that `login_required` can see?

Comment: The answer is here: http://blog.macuyiko.com/post/2016/fixing-flask-url_for-when-behind-mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 3):

As described here:

http://blog.macuyiko.com/post/2016/fixing-flask-url_for-when-behind-mod_proxy.html

Create a class that extends the app.wsgi_app class and wraps it.